# How to repeat Toolbar background image programatically?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

How do I style a Toolbar at runtime with a repeated image (not using the xml styles)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method, add the following:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.IMAGE_TO_REPEAT);
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
bitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```